# Extracción de string con base a variable en SQL

Tags: sql, string, variables, split, substring

Tengo una tabla con nombre de títulos de libros el cual, suele tener "duplicidad" por dicho campo, ya que cuenta con la descripción del idioma en el que esta el titulo.

Ejemplo:

1. Libro X
2. Libro X Spanish
3. Libro X - German
4. Libro X | Portuguese (EU)

No siempre cuenta con algo para identificar la exactitud de donde estará la descripción del idioma, puede tener un espacio, un guion o demás. La verdad es variado y con esto en mente se me ocurrió la siguiente consulta basado el quitar dichas descripciones en base a una variable para ir agregando casos que puedan salir a futuro:

```
DECLARE @Titles     TABLE ([title] VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Titles VALUES ('Libro X'),('Libro X Spanish'),('Libro X - German'),('Libro Y'),('Libro Y - Spanish'),('Libro Y German')
DECLARE @Filtro     VARCHAR(99) = 'Spanish,German,Portuguese (EU)'


SELECT  DISTINCT [title]
                ,[new_name] = IIF(PATINDEX('%' + T2.VALUE+'%', [title])>0
                                    ,SUBSTRING([title],1, IIF(CHARINDEX(T2.VALUE, [title]) <=0 ,LEN([title]),PATINDEX('%' + T2.VALUE+'%', [title]) )-1 )
                                    ,[title])
FROM @Titles AS T1
LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Filtro,',') AS T2 ON 1=1
```

Este código cuenta con un fallo ya que me retorna mas títulos de los que están declarados.
La idea seria tener el siguiente resultado:

1. Libro X
2. Libro Y

¡Gracias!

Comment: No puedo comentar por mi puntuación<50 ya que esta no es una respuesta con código pero te dejo algunas opciones: - Definir todos los separadores en algún lado e ir jugando con las cadenas para los valores (fácil pero no es certero y costará mantenerlo, tampoco es eficiente)
- Algoritmo basado en probabilidades en el cual se busca las raíces de los libros y se comparan con otros usando los filtros que pusiste así se detecta el libro raíz de cada familia (Libro X y Libro Y) - Esto te serviría mejor pero hay que jugar con ese algoritmo
- La mejor opción la cual sería la más performante es que mod

Comment: Lo siento pero parece una misión imposible. Estás trabajando sobre cadenas de texto que aunque se refieren al mismo libro pueden estar escritas de forma diferente. Yo me quedaría con la solución que ya tienes que aunque no muestra exactamente, de forma limpia, la información como tu quieres, termina logrando su comentido de mostrar los libros basados en el filtro de idioma.

Comment: Ninguna solución será perfecta. Tienes que considerar que hay libros que pueden tener títulos similares que no corresponden al mismo. Por ejemplo, puedes tener un libro que se llame "El Paciente" y otro que se llame "El Paciente Inglés" (ya sé que es una película) y serán libros distintos que podrían ser tomados como iguales en distintos idiomas. Toda solución requerirá de una revisión manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa tabla debería de estar normalizada, además de tener los datos limpios. No tiene lógica tener un `libro x Spanish` y un `libro - y Spanish`. O ambos tienen guión o ambos no lo tienen.

```
Create table dbo.Titles
                      (
                      title VARCHAR(50)
                      );

INSERT INTO dbo.Titles
VALUES
       ( 'Libro Z' ),
       ( 'Libro X' ),
       ( 'Libro X Spanish' ),
       ( 'Libro X - German' ),
       ( 'Libro Y' ),
       ( 'Libro Y - Spanish' ),
       ( 'Libro Y German' );
```

He convertido la variable tipo table, en una tabla, para poder ir mostrando los pasos de un modo sencillo. Además de añadir un `Libro Z`

Lo primero es splitear por el filtro, pero no con un `left join`, sino con el `operador apply`.

**Aproximación:**

```
DECLARE @Filtro VARCHAR(99) = 'Spanish,German,Portuguese (EU)';

Select
      title 
    , value 
    From dbo.Titles 
    Cross apply string_split(@Filtro,',') fn
```

[image: Res1]

Parece claro que de los resultados mostrados, tenemos que quedarnos solo con las filas, donde la parte derecha de title coincida con value.

```
DECLARE @Filtro VARCHAR(99) = 'Spanish,German,Portuguese (EU)';

Select
      title 
    , value 
    From dbo.Titles t1
    Cross apply string_split(@Filtro,',') fn
    where RIGHT(t1.title,LEN(fn.value))= fn.value
```

[image: Res2]

Ahora solo nos queda limpiar del título la parte derecha de value.

```
DECLARE @Filtro VARCHAR(99) = 'Spanish,German,Portuguese (EU)';

Select
      
    left(t1.title,len(t1.title)-len(fn.value)) as title
    From dbo.Titles t1
    Cross apply string_split(@Filtro,',') fn
    where RIGHT(t1.title,LEN(fn.value))= fn.value;
```

[image: Res3]

El problema de tener la info "no Limpia". Ya que unos libros contienen unos separadores y otros no.

Ahora para limpiar ese guión, voy a usar una expresión case.

**Consulta Real**

```
DECLARE @Filtro VARCHAR(99) = 'Spanish,German,Portuguese (EU)';

Select distinct 
       case
           when Trim(Right(Left(t1.title,
       Len(t1.title) - Len(fn.value)), 2)) = '-' then Left(t1.title,
       Len(t1.title) - Len(fn.value) - 2)
       else Left(t1.title,
       Len(t1.title) - Len(fn.value))
       end as title
       From dbo.Titles AS t1
            Cross apply String_Split(@Filtro, ',') AS fn
       where Right(t1.title, Len(fn.value)) = fn.value;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: ¡Magistral la explicación! Gracias por colaborar en esta problemática.